# Post method not working : jquery spring restful webservice with java

Tags: web-services, rest, post, jquery-ajaxq

When the service is being called by using method as **GET**, it works smoothly i.e. request.getParameter("userValue") is printed.

 *But while using **Post** method, it prints **null** for request.getParameter("userValue").*

**HTML code** : (jsonObject has valid json)

```
var myData = "userValue=" + jsonObject ;
     jQuery.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "http://localhost:8080/Webservice_JS_26Oct/FieldsToFile/write",
                  data: myData,
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
```

**Java Code:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/FieldsToFile")    
    public class FileWriter {

            @RequestMapping(value = "/write", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")

            public String getData(HttpServletRequest request) throws  IOException, IllegalStateException, ServletException {

                String jsonString = request.getParameter("userValue") ;
                System.out.println("jsonString = " + jsonString);
                String myData = request.getParameter("myData") ;
```

I am new to this, Please advise how to make it work for POST method.

Comment: Request everyone to look into this query. Thanks.

Comment: Request to look into this query. Nobody has responded. Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone please check this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.getInputStream()` to print the request body part. I suggest that  your `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`  can be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `HttpServletRequest request` can be `@Requestbody ..`